# Postgres: Perform statement and limit

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query which I run every night.

```
perform distinct fn_debtor_summary( clientacc) from client where not clientacc is null;
```

However because the function is quite slow, when I debug I like to debug off a small subset of data, so I use the following query.

```
 perform distinct fn_debtor_summary( clientacc) from client where not clientacc is null limit 10;
```

However I find that the limit doesn't work and it runs the function against the whole table.

Any ideas why this is happening and how I could run it against a small subset of the data without creating temporary tables?

Comment: You need to pass the limit into the satements inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL runs functions on every row in the PERFORM query, before applying the limit. So even through it returns only 10, it will still run the function more than 10 times.

the solution is to use a subquery, interestingly PERFORM doesnt work, but a SELECT will work as well.

```
select fn_debtor_summary( limitclients.clientacc) from (select clientacc from client limit 1) limitclients;
```